# RDLC display nothing after loading data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I have a RDLC contain 14 tablix in each rectangle. the data is get from Stored Procedure and using dataset to pass it to the reportviewer.

The ReportViewer taking so long processing time, it's taking about 2 minutes. and after processing is complete, the ReportViewer display nothing, not even the header.

I have debugged it. The Dataset is filled by data returning from Stored Procedure, and it's passed to ReportViewer. and the ReportViewer starts green loading circle for a 2 minutes and more, and it's display nothing.

Why is this happen? I guess it's timeout or something. I need your help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you remove all table or keep just one and see if your report can load ?

Comment: Yes, it can load if there's only 1 tablix. In my report, 8 tablix has an calculation in expression. it can heavily affect the reportviewer?

Comment: Not sure what make your problem. Maybe try add about 3-4 tablix at once then test to figure out it's connection timeout error or some syntax error. I guess it's not connection timeout because you use Stored Procedure. Hope you solve it soon.